# Resolving an approach for two setters affecting each other

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios5, getter-setter

I have a custom class, holding a string for gender, and a bool value for server interaction.

.h

```
@interface Member : NSObject
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gender;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isMale;
...
```

.m

```
    - (void)setIsMale:(BOOL)isMale
    {
        _isMale = isMale;

        if (isMale) {
            self.gender = @"Male";
        }
        else {
            self.gender = @"Female";
        }
    }
```

Also I want to do the opposite of it, which means when gender is changed to female, I want my isMale property to be set to NO.  But If define a setter for the gender as well, those two setters will be in an infinite loop. Is there a  way to implement that 2 private setters that wont loop each other?

This would be the code which will result in the infitine loop

```
- (void)setGender:(NSString *)gender
{
    _gender = gender;

    if ([gender isEqualToString:@"Male"]) {
        self.isMale = YES;
    }
    else if ([gender isEqualToString:@"Female"]) {
        self.isMale = NO;
    }
    else {
        // discard...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of the laughing third, or "Divide et impera":

```
- (void)setIsMale:(BOOL)male
{
    [self setIsMaleInternal:male];
}

- (void)setGender:(NSString *)_gen
{
    if ([_gen isEqualToString:@"male"]) {
        [self setIsMaleInternal:YES];
    } else if ([_gen isEqualToString:@"female"]) {
        [self setIsMaleInternal:NO];
    } else {
        [World burn]; // or just an exception?
    }
}

- (void)setIsMaleInternal:(BOOL)flag
{
    _isMale = flag;
    if (flag) {
        _gender = @"male";
    } else {
        _gender = @"female";
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't put the second `else` there. `isMale` says nothing about being female or some third gender :) In another words, if `isMale` is false, it could be anything else!

Comment: @iMartin Well, that's exactly why the second else is there. If the gender, which seems to have only two valid states, is neither male nor female, that's an error, isn't it?

Comment: lol. I am just creating a member class for interacting with a server. But yeah :)

Comment: @H2CO3 What I mean is, that if the person has `gender` _"alien"_, the property `isMale` should be _NO_. No exception, no burning ;)

Comment: server takes a parameter called gender, and it is true on male and false on female

Comment: @iMartin Oh, I see your reasoning :) Well, let the OP decide that.

Answer (score 2):

What about not storing `isMale` in ivar? This is what I would do:

```
// `gender` is auto-synthesized

- (BOOL)isMale {
    return [self.gender isEqualToString:@"male"];
}

- (void)setIsMale:(BOOL)isMale {
    self.gender = @"male";
}


// In case you use KVO
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsAffectingValueForIsMale {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"gender"];
}
```

Comment: +1 as the first answer to use `keyPathsAffectingValueFor...` - i.e. to use dependent properties which is the right way to handle two (or more) mutually dependent properties.

Answer (score 1):

> This would be the code which will result in the infinite loop

That is correct: if you use setters inside setters, you would get an infinite recursion. That is why you should set instance variables rather than properties inside your setters<sup>+</sup>. Another solution would be checking the current value: if a property is being set to the value that it already holds, the setter should exit.

However, in your case the problem should be solved differently: rather than storing two attributes, you should store one, and compute the other. Keep the `isMale`, and provide both a getter and a setter for the `gender` property:

```
-(NSString*)gender {
    return _isMale ? @"Male" : @"Female";
}
-(void)setGender:(NSString*)gender {
    if ([gender isEqualToString@"Male"]) {
        _isMale = YES;
    } else if ([gender isEqualToString@"Female"]) {
        _isMale = NO;
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

This is one of very important principles of object-oriented designs (indeed, any data designs): you should not store things that can be easily calculated "on the fly". The classic example is the `birthday` + `current_age` pair: you should store the `birthday`, and calculate the `current_age` to avoid inconsistencies.

---

<sup>+</sup> This was not generally true before ARC, and even with ARC you may want to use setters for string attributes marked as `copy`.

Comment: If I could mark 2 correct answers, I would marks yours as well and thanks for pointing to the exact issue. But I just wanted to see how to resolve this issue if I cannot edit the data structure. Thanks for your advices though !

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to reference the iVars directly in each setter...

```
- (void)setIsMale:(BOOL)isMale
{
    _isMale = isMale;

    if (isMale) {
        _gender = @"Male";
    }
    else {
        _gender = @"Female";
    }
}
```

However, since isMale is essentially derived do you even need a property for it? Could you just expose an isMale method?

```
- (BOOL) isMale {
   return [self.gender isEqualToString:@"Male"];
}
```

Comment: that was more than suitable for this exact problem. I just wanted to see another way of doing, in case there was no way out of this. But thanks !

Comment: Yep! If you have to use two properties, the technique would be hitting the backing variables directly through the _variable notion. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to check for the equal values in setters:

```
- (void)setIsMale:(BOOL)isMale {
    if (_isMale != isMale) {
        _isMale = isMale;

        self.gender = (isMale? @"male" : @"female");
    }
}

- (void)setGender:(NSString *)gender {
    // this is not perfect, you have to take nils into account
    if ([_gender isEqualToString:gender]) {
        _gender = gender;

        self.isMale = [_gender isEqualToString:@"male"];
    }
}
```

After setting both values once, the conditions would fail and then break the infinite recursion.